# Ajax callback called multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a ajax-call to a script for searching numbers. The response is a json array with name and surname(Strings). The client-script is this and I think really don't see why the script is looping and sending the response multiple times. The toogle-solution was the last thing I tried.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#phone").keyup(function () {
        var number = $(this).val();
        var toogle = 0;

        if (number.length == 10 && toogle == 0) {
            alert('inside with 10 numbers');
            toogle = 1;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "info-phone.php",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    number: number
                }
            }).done(function (msg) {
                toogle = 0;
                if (msg.Name != "" && msg.Surname != "") {
                    $("#phone").add("Are you " + msg.Name + " " + msg.Surname);
                };
            }); //done-function
        }
    }); //phone-keyup
}); //document-ready
```

Basically I have a input, and when the user reaches 10 numbers this script will call the server and get the name to that number.

Any ideas? Just a typo?

Comment: The server side workes just fine with this echo:
echo($_GET['callback'] . "(" . json_encode($result) . ");");

Comment: You should atleast try to declare the `toggle` variable outside of the `keyup()`

Comment: Please call ajax on focus out of that text box it will work.

Comment: "on focus out of that box" you mean on blur? I think the current method is better as it'll suggest the surname when the input reaches 10 chars, rather than suggesting it when the user tries to move to the next field.

Comment: The solution is working, i get respons and write it out, but it's a bit weird that its called multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.toogle = 0;
    $("#phone").click(function () {
        var number = $(this).val();

        if (number.length == 10 && window.toogle == 0) {
            alert('inside with 10 numbers');
            window.toogle = 1;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "info-phone.php",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    number: number
                }
            }).done(function (msg) {
                window.toogle = 0;
                if (msg.Name != "" && msg.Surname != "") {
                    $("#phone").add("Are you " + msg.Name + " " + msg.Surname);
                }
            }); //done-function
        }
    }); //phone-keyup
}); //document-ready
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you're using .length which measures the length of strings, on the return of the jQuery .val() method, which returns strings or "numbers". As your input is a phone number, I think the .val() method is returning an integer, and you'd need to convert it to a string for .length to work correctly.

Try

```
number.toString().length;
```

Comment: As a test, I think if you enter a mix of alphanumeric characters instead of a phone number, .val() will return a string and your current script will work correctly, only firing the ajax request on the 10th input.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you should not write anonymous functions with several identations.
Just name your functions to see clearer in that mess!

Your variables number and toogle are local to the anonymous function you call doing keyup.
I think there might be a problem here no?

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.toogle = 0;
    $("#phone").click(phoneKeyUp); //phone-keyup -> this one you declare it to make document.ready() clearer
}); //document-ready


var phoneKeyUp = function() {

    var number = $(this).val();

    if (number.length == 10 && window.toogle == 0) {
        alert('inside with 10 numbers');
        window.toogle = 1;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "info-phone.php",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                number: number
            }
        }).done(function (msg) {
            window.toogle = 0;
            if (msg.Name != "" && msg.Surname != "") {
                $("#phone").add("Are you " + msg.Name + " " + msg.Surname);
            }
        }); //done-function -> this one may stay here
    }
};
```